# Access Dropbox file list inside public folder with public url

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I want to implement dropbox in my java project.

User: If suppose you want to take a printout, instead of carrying a pendrive or sending it to your gmail id, you will just drop that file into on of the folder inside the public folder of the dropbox. 
So after reaching the printout shop you will just navigate to the link http://{host}/myfiles. Here it will show the list of file which are there in that perticular folder inside the public dropbox folder, after clicking of a perticular list item it wll download the file, then the user can select a file and give print.

Is there a way to get the file list along with public url in dropbox using Java ?

Comment: Do you want to drag and drop your files ? Or just transfer them from one source to another ?
Is your destination going to be a FTP server ? Try MultiPartFile

Answer (score 0):

You can use the createShareableUrl method to get a link for viewing the document. To get the file list, you can try

```
DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren(root);
```

The listing is a list of DbxEntry object of the folder. It can be either a file or a folder. For folder you just need do the same thing repeatedly until reach the end.

Answer (score 0):

In Android case, you can create objects **DropboxLink** for each path in the folder you want, for example, "/Public/", and get their parameter **url**:

```
   private DropboxAPI<?> dropbox;
```

...

```
   ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Entry directory = dropbox.metadata(path, 1000, null, true, null);
        for (Entry entry : directory.contents) {
            files.add(entry.fileName() + ": "+ files.add(entry.path));
            DropboxLink link = dropbox.share(entry.path);
            files.add(link.url);
        }

    } catch (DropboxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```